# Why SASS @each statement not working in Next.js?

Tags: css, sass, next.js

I have a scss file with my color scheme

**_colors.scss**

```
@import './variables';

$colors: (
  p: $color-primary,
  s: $color-secondary,
  t: $color-tertiary,
  q: $color-quartary,
);

@each $name, $hsl in $colors {
  .c-#{name} {
    color: $hsl;
  }
  .bg-#{name} {
    background: $hsl;
  }
}
```

And file with variables

**_variables.scss**

```
$color-primary: hsl(113, 99%, 53%);
$color-secondary: hsl(0, 7%, 19%);
$color-tertiary: hsl(0, 7%, 78%);
$color-quartary: hsl(2, 87%, 48%);
```

And finally

**main.scss**

```
@import './variables';
@import './colors';

body {
  color: $color-tertiary;
  background-color: $color-secondary;
}
```

> So the question is why I can't use the classes generated in *@each* which should be **c-p**, **bg-p**, **c-s**, *etc*.

If I manually define for example **c-p** class

```
.c-p {
  color: $color-primary;
}
```

It doesn't matter where I define it in _*colors.scss* or *main.scss* and either it before or after *@each* statement. It works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop currently generates CSS classes like `.bg-name` and `.c-name` as you're using the string `name` instead of the variable `$name`. The following should work:

```
@each $name, $hsl in $colors {
  .c-#{$name} {
    color: $hsl;
  }
  .bg-#{$name} {
    background: $hsl;
  }
}
```